# How to transfer data from sql to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, svg

I work with this example: https://www.sitepoint.com/dynamic-geo-maps-svg-jquery/ But I need get data from MySql DB.

I have 2 main files:
1) map.php (connect to db and show svg map)
2) map.js (show colorized map with static data)

In JS file I see rows:

```
enter code here
var regions=[
    {
        "region_name": "Lombardia",
        "region_code": "lom",
        "population": 9794525
    },
    {
        "region_name": "Campania",
        "region_code": "cam",
        "population": 5769750
    },
    // etc ...
];
```

I need change value of region name to value from db. But I do not how?

In my php main variable are:

```
echo "Region: ".$row['region_name']."
echo "Code of region: ".$row['region_code']."
echo "Value: ".$row['value']."
```

Comment: You should make a request to `map.php` file (with AJAX) in order to get the desired data formatted for example in JSON and in JS callback method insert them into your array.

Comment: JQuery has an AJAX function you can use. AJAX allows you to access the database via server-side without posting the page. Here's a link to JQuery's ajax documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I need change php or js file, or create new file?

Comment: Do you already have the map.php? What does it return?

Comment: I have map.php now it is test file and return only php data from mysql in my example the data from DB as region_name and region_code and and value. [link]http://freesite.zzz.com.ua/svg/ the first part - is test data from mysql. Next You canm see 3 square and if You onmouseover You can see data, but this is local data, not from DB

Answer (score 1):

Normally you won't be modifying your js file. Instead you need to load your data from DB using i.e. an ajax call and then "give" it to the control you're using.
To do that you need  i.e. a web service that returns your data and some javascript function that calls it. You can do something like this:

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "map.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
}).done(function(data ) {
    refresh_your_map(data);
});
```

check https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ for more details

Edited - do something like this:

```
/* define this function in your js file*/
var getRegionsData = function()
{
    var result =[];
    $.ajax({ url: 'map.php', 
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
          result = data;
       }
    });
    return result;
}

//then do this 
var regions=getRegionsData();
//the rest of your code from map.js
```

Comment: what is `refresh_your_map(data);` ? it is my var from php such as `region_name`?

Comment: it's just a function name I picked that could contain your logic like processing/binding the retrieved SQL data.  i.e. changing colors of retrieved regions etc

Comment: can You check listing below? I do not know, what i need write in map.js file

Answer (score 1):

First of all your **PHP code** should connect to the database, extract the data you are interested in and build a json string from it, just like the `regions` data from your example. Your PHP will return this json. You will probably want to work with json because it is the most ajax/js friendly format.

Your **JS code** should make a Ajax call to that PHP for retrieving the json formatted data. Assuming you are using jquery, it is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "map.php",
    dataType : "json",
    done: function(data){
       // the data parameter is the json returned by the php
       // already converted to javascript object...
       // Just like the regions array from your example.
    }
});
```

For further information and options about the jquery ajax api, see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax.

Comment: I try do it but it difficult for me:
In my php strings:

`echo "Region: ".$row['region_name']."
echo "Code of region: ".$row['region_code']."
echo "Value: ".$row['value']."`

Comment: If I add region_name in my function(data) I havent't result

Comment: Your php could be something like this: echo `'{"regions":[{"region_name":"'.$row['region_name'].'","region_code":"'.$row['region_code'].'","population":"'.$row['value'].'"}]}'`. And, for instance, your js for getting the population of the first region returned by the php could be: `var value = data.regions[0].population;`

Comment: I try it again but it do not work. I think, tyhat You understand what I need. So  I insert svg file in main index.php file it connect to db too. Other file is java, it have data for all svg objects such as region name? region code and value, this file colorize all svg object by rerion code. I need take all data from Mysql and replace it to java file as data. **I take full listing of my files in post below, help me :)**

Comment: You see, that `var regions` in map.js has static data. In php I think, that I wrote query, but i do not how i can do it on javascript.

Comment: Try to separate the dynamic data from the static content of your html. I would work with 3 files: (1) a map.html with the static content from your current map.php file. So it would contain all the html structure, the map.js import, the svg map, etc. (2) a mapData.php file which queries the database and returns the population data json. (3) a map.js similar to your current js file that, instead of working with a static regions array, retrieves the same array from the mapData.php using the ajax service that we were discussing.

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**

```
enter code here
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="map.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
<title>Моя карта</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "happy_user";
$password = "1234567890";
$dbname = "freesite_zzz_com_ua";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT region_name, region_code, value FROM map";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "region_name: " . $row["region_name"]. " region_code: " .          
$row["region_code"]. " value: " . $row["value"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>

<h1>svg map</h1>

<div class="map">

<svg version="1.1" id="map_x5F_id" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"     
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="595.3px" height="841.9px" viewBox="0 0 595.3 841.9" style="enable-        
background:new 0 0 595.3 841.9;" xml:space="preserve"
>

<g id="id_x5F_1">
<rect x="58" y="163" width="85" height="85"/>
</g>
<g id="id_x5F_2">
<rect x="143" y="163" width="85" height="85"/>
</g>
<g id="id_x5F_3">
<rect x="228.1" y="163" width="85" height="85"/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**map.js:**

```
var regions=[
{
    "region_name": "region-1",
    "region_code": "id_x5F_1",
    "value": "10"
},
{
    "region_name": "region-2",
    "region_code": "id_x5F_2",
    "value": "20"
},
{
    "region_name": "region-3",
    "region_code": "id_x5F_3",
    "value": "30"
}
];

var temp_array = regions.map(function(item){
return item.value;
});

var highest_value = Math.max.apply(Math, temp_array);

$(function() {

for(i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {

    $('#'+ regions[i].region_code)
    .css({'fill': 'rgba(11, 104, 170,' + regions[i].value/highest_value     
+')'})
    .data('region', regions[i]);
}

$('.map g').mouseover(function (e) {
    var region_data=$(this).data('region');
    $('<div class="info_panel">'+
        region_data.region_name + '<br>' +
        'value: ' + region_data.value.toLocaleString("en-UK") +
        '</div>'
     )
    .appendTo('body');
})
.mouseleave(function () {
    $('.info_panel').remove();
})
.mousemove(function(e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX, //X coordinates of mouse
        mouseY = e.pageY; //Y coordinates of mouse

    $('.info_panel').css({
        top: mouseY-50,
        left: mouseX - ($('.info_panel').width()/2)
    });
});
});
```